# Conditional probability for random variables with different distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, where $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $1$ and $Y$ has uniform distribution on $[-1,1]$ interval. Find $\mathbb{P}(Y>0|X+Y>1)$.

My attempt was to use the definition of conditional probability and calculate $\mathbb{P}(Y>0|X+Y>1)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y>0,X+Y>1)}{\mathbb{P}(X+Y>1)}$, but the thing is, I don't know how to find the numerator of this fraction.

$g_X(x)=e^{-x}$

$g_Y(x)=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}(x)$

$$\begin{align}g_{X+Y}(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g_X(x)g_Y(t-x)\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}(t-x)\ dx = \int_{t-1}^{t+1}e^{-x}\ dx = -e^{-x}\Big |_{t-1}^{t+1} = \\&=\frac{1}{e^{t-1}}-\frac{1}{e^{t+1}} = \frac{e^2-1}{e^{t+1}}\end{align}$$

$$\mathbb{P}(X+Y>1) = \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^2-1}{e^{t+1}}\ dt = \frac{e^2-1}{e}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^t} = \frac{e^2-1}{e}\left(-e^{-t}\Big|_1^{\infty}\right) = \frac{e^2-1}{e^2} = 1-\frac{1}{e^2}$$

What I've done so far, is it even correct?

Comment: Did you note that the numerical result proposed in the accepted answer is wrong (hence also some steps of the proof leading to it)? Does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my way to find the denominator:
$$\begin{align}
\Pr(X+Y>1) & = \Pr(Y>1-X)
\\[1ex] & = \Pr(Y>1-X, X<2) +\Pr(Y>-1, X\geq 2)
\\[1ex] & = \int_0^2 \int_{1-x}^{1} e^{-x}\cdot \frac 12 \operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x
+\int_2^\infty \int_{-1}^{1} e^{-x}\cdot \frac 12 \operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x
\\[1ex] & = \frac 12\int_0^2 y\mid_{1-x}^{1} e^{-x} \operatorname{d}x
+\frac 12\int_2^\infty y\mid_{-1}^{1} e^{-x} \operatorname{d}x
\\[1ex] & = \frac 12\int_0^2 x\; e^{-x} \operatorname{d}x
+\frac 12\int_2^\infty 2\; e^{-x} \operatorname{d}x
\\[1ex] & = \frac 12\bigl[ (x-1)\; e^{-x}\bigr]_{x=0}^{x=2} 
+ \frac 12\bigl[ 2\; e^{-x}\bigr]_{x=2}^{x\to\infty}
\\[1ex] & = \frac 12(e^{-2}+1) + \frac 12(0-2e^{-2})
\\[1ex] & = \frac 12(1-e^{-2})
\end{align}$$
So to find the numerator
$$\begin{align}
\Pr(Y>0,X+Y>1) & = \Pr(Y>0,Y>1-X)
\\[1ex] & = \Pr(Y>1-X, X<1) +\Pr(Y>0, X\geq 1)
\\[1ex] & = \int_0^1 \int_{1-x}^{1} e^{-x}\cdot\frac 12 \operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x
+\int_1^\infty \int_{-1}^{1} e^{-x}\cdot \frac 12 \operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x
\\[1ex] & = \frac 12\int_0^1 y\mid_{1-x}^{1} e^{-x} \operatorname{d}x
+\frac 12\int_1^\infty y\mid_{-1}^{1} e^{-x} \operatorname{d}x
\\[1ex] & = \frac 12\int_0^1 x\; e^{-x} \operatorname{d}x
+\frac 12\int_1^\infty 2\; e^{-x} \operatorname{d}x
\\[1ex] & = \frac 12\bigl[ (x-1)\; e^{-x}\bigr]_{x=0}^{x=1} 
+ \frac 12\bigl[ 2\; e^{-x}\bigr]_{x=1}^{x\to\infty}
\\[1ex] & = \frac 12(0+1) + \frac 12(0-2e^{-1})
\\[1ex] & = \frac 12(1-2e^{-1})
\end{align}$$ 
Thus:
$$\begin{align}
\Pr(Y>0\mid X+Y>1) & = \frac{1-2\;e^{-1}}{1-e^{-2}}
\\[1ex] & \frac{e^2-2\;e}{e^2-1}
\\[1ex] & \approx 0.305{\small 6}\ldots
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

The usual method, applied as **un**-cleverly as possible: by independence of $X$ and $Y$, $$P(X+Y\gt1)=\int_0^\infty P(x+Y\gt1)\,f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty P(Y\gt1-x)\,\mathrm e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx.$$ Now, for every $x\gt0$, $P(Y\gt1-x)=\min\left\{\frac12x,1\right\}$ hence $$P(X+Y\gt1)=\int_0^2\tfrac12x\mathrm e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx+\int_2^\infty\mathrm e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx=\ ...$$
Likewise, $$P(Y\gt0,X+Y\gt1)=\int_0^\infty P(Y\gt1-x,Y\gt0)\,\mathrm e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx.$$ Now, for every $x\gt0$, $P(Y\gt1-x,Y\gt0)=\min\left\{\frac12x,\frac12\right\}$ hence $$P(Y\gt0,X+Y\gt1)=\int_0^1\tfrac12x\mathrm e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx+\int_1^\infty\tfrac12\mathrm e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx=\ ...$$ To help you check your computations, the final result is $P(Y\gt0\mid X+Y\gt1)=\frac{\mathrm e}{\mathrm e+1}\approx0.731$ (and the fact that this value is greater than $\frac12$ should come as a relief...).